# Child view controllers in UIViewController

Tags: ios, uisplitviewcontroller

I have one screen where I want to show master-detail interface. But I need master to be hideable with animation. As far as I know UISplitViewController doesn't support that.

So, instead I made one UIViewController and added two child controllers to him.

In this container view controller I do:

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.masterViewController = [[MasterViewController alloc] init];
        [self addChildViewController:self.masterViewController];

        self.detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] init];
        [self addChildViewController:self.detailViewController];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.masterViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 256, 748);
    [self.view addSubview:self.masterViewController.view];

    self.detailViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(256, 0, 768, 748);
    [self.view addSubview:self.detailViewController.view];
}
```

But the result is a complete mess. It doesnt change frame properly.

What is the correct way to mimic master-detail properly when I have two view controllers (each one has his own superclass)?

Comment: Try this custom [split controller](http://mattgemmell.com/2010/07/31/mgsplitviewcontroller-for-ipad/)

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't change frame properly"?

Comment: **typicalFlow**, this library too old. We cant use that in production. And I believe that this is possible without some big library. **Justin Paulson**, both views stratify each other and have sizes completely different from what I wrote in code.